# Is there an equivalent to the Java 'static' keyword in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I want to call `change1` in `CallerOne` contract, then call `Get2` in contract `CallerTwo` and get the output as

> 1

The only way I think it could be solved is by making variable `p` a static variable, but solidity seems to not have that functionality.

Here is the standard code which I want to change so as to allow `p` in contract `CallerOne` to pick up a new value from contract `CallerTwo`:

```
contract master{

 uint  p;
    function changep()public {
p=1;
}
function getP()public returns(uint){
return p;
}
}


contract CallerOne is master {
function change1()public{
    changep();
}
function Get1() public returns(uint){
    return getP();
}

}
contract CallerTwo is master{
function change2()public{
    changep();
}
function Get2() public returns(uint){
    return getP();
}
}
```

after I follow the steps I mentioned above, I receive the output

> 0

I have tried using an interface of `contract master` in both `CallerOne` and `CallerTwo` contracts.
This yields the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how Smart Contracts work. Most characteristics of Smart Contract programming are similar to Object-Oriented Programming, yet they don't share the same aspects.

To answer your question, no, you can't make static contracts similar to in OOP static classes, because every contract is independent and works as a single program.

So, in your case, you can inherit traits from other contracts, but 2 contracts inheriting from the same parent won't share the same parent state, since each child contract instance is independent of the other, and has its own child and parent state ( inherited functions, variables...).

To archive what you want, you should first deploy your parent contract, and create a variable that references that contract in your children, and call from there.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Master {
  uint p;

  function changep()public {
    p = 1;
  }

  // we use the view mutator, that way we tell the compiler that this function wont change the state of the blockchain ( change state variable p value ).
  function getP() public view returns(uint) {
    return p;
  }
}


contract CallerOne {

  Master m;

  constructor(address _m) {
    m = Master(_m);
  }

  function change1() public {
    m.changep();
  }

  function Get1() public view returns(uint) {
    return m.getP();
  }
}

contract CallerTwo {

  Master m;

  constructor(address _m) {
    m = Master(_m);
  }

  function change2() public {
    m.changep();
  }

  function Get2() public view returns(uint) {
    return m.getP();
  }
}
```